# Under predictions in Time series forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, prediction

I have a time series which has increasing trend and is seasonal. I build a `TSLM` model, with `trend()` and `season()`. Now, when I use this time-series model to predict in test data, the predictions are always under the actuals. Below is the reproducible code. I have noticed that the under predictions are always between the months March through June, even if I test on different years. I also tried to add `knots` in trend at `1913`.
The data is from sales of a commodity product(cold drinks).

```
library(lubridate)
library(forecast)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(feasts)
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amandeepfj/RawData/master/time-series.csv") %>% 
        mutate(year_mon = yearmonth(year_mon)) %>%
        as_tsibble()

dts_train <- df %>% head(-6)

fable_models <- dts_train %>% 
  model(
    tslm = TSLM(y ~ trend() + season())
  )

fable_models %>% gg_tsresiduals()

augment(fable_models)

dts_test <- df %>% tail(6)

forecast(fable_models, new_data = dts_test, level = 95) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  select(year_mon, .model, predicted = .mean) %>%
  inner_join(dts_test, by = c("year_mon")) %>% 
  mutate(.resid = y - predicted)
```

The decomposition of time-series suggests that the trend component has cycle before `1914`.

```
dts_train %>% 
  model(
    STL(y ~ trend() + season(window='periodic'), robust = TRUE)) %>%
  components() %>%
  autoplot()
```

[image]

Not programming language specific question, above a working sample in `R`.

Link to data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amandeepfj/RawData/master/time-series.csv

Comment: Your code is *not* reproducible, since we don't have your data file. Consider editing your post to include data you generate (with a preset RNG seed, `set.seed()`).

Comment: We need to know what method creates your 'time series model' as well. There are many different types of time series models and they make very different assumptions.  One thing that may have occurred is that the process may have changed since you built your model - you essentially have a structural break. There could be seasonality in your data which you have not modeled as well. Are you asking what caused the problem or what it would take to fix it, I am not sure what your question is. You could build weights to correct your error if its consistent over time.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: I just checked, the data is publicly accessible. I will add a `URL`, too.

Comment: @user54285: I am looking for ideas to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's plot the forecasts:

```r
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
library(dplyr)

df <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amandeepfj/RawData/master/time-series.csv") %>% 
  mutate(year_mon = yearmonth(year_mon)) %>%
  as_tsibble()

dts_train <- df %>% head(-6)

fable_models <- dts_train %>% 
  model(
    tslm = TSLM(y ~ trend() + season())
  )

dts_test <- df %>% tail(6)

forecast(fable_models, new_data = dts_test, level=95) %>%
  autoplot(df)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As you can see, the actual values are within the prediction intervals, so there is no evidence of a problem with the model. The fact that the observations are above the point forecasts for all 6 forecast horizons is not necessarily a problem -- forecast errors in the test data will usually be positively correlated.

You can get a better model if use ARIMA rather than TSLM:

```r
fable_models <- dts_train %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(y))

forecast(fable_models, new_data = dts_test, level=95) %>%
  autoplot(df)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is a practitioner not statisticians advice (since I am not the later). There are several ways to approach this. Ideally, but its very difficult in practice, you can try to find out why the model you developed departs from the actual results. It would help greatly to know which time series method you are using in that regard since they will address this differently. ARIMA, ESM, ARDL.....there are many more. There might be outliers, there might be a structural break or process change, and many other things. If you know what is wrong then there are suggested solutions for many of them. Simplest way to do address the problem is to generate a ratio between what you predict and what you get and create a counter weight to address this.  So if the answer is consistently 2 and you predict 1 you can multiply future answers by .5 We do that where I work to deal with the problems in the models created by the covid-19 (except we re-estimate each month based on the last month discrepancy because we don't assume the error is consistent). Of course then you have to see if it works with future data (and the process or external reality means it may not). Another option is to change the time series method you are using.